# In python how can i fix list index out of range problem?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, indexoutofrangeexception

In python, I want to print each index of the list if the previous index has no value. how to print the next index how can I fix this problem
I am trying web scraping and I want to get values for the website which have 
how can I use if loop to fix this problem?

this is my sample code:

```
hotel_add = container.findAll("div",{"class":"is-hidden-mobile blEntry address 
ui_link_container level_4"})

hotel_add_srt= container.findAll("span",{"class":"street-address"})
Add1 = hotel_add_srt[0].text

hotel_add_ext= container.findAll("span",{"class":"extended-address"})
if
Add2 = hotel_add_ext[0].text
```

Comment: can you show the data from each variable?  it doesn't help too much to just show some variables that are not defined like `container`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if hotel_add_srt:
  Add1 = hotel_add_srt[0].text
```